# Restoring full backup to Ubuntu Server with rsync

Tags: server, backup, rsync

First a little background: Last weekend I set up RAID 5 with new disks I got for my homelab server.  Because I set up raid for the first time it would delete all of my data.  With this in mind before I set up RAID, I made an rsync backup of my entire Ubuntu server system using this command:

```
sudo rsync -aAXv / --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*", "/mnt/*","/media/*",”/ssh/*”,"/lost+found"} /mnt
```

Everything backed up fine so I went ahead, set up RAID, and then did a fresh install of Ubuntu Server. I then plugged the drive in, mounted it and ran this command to restore the backup:

```
sudo rsync -aAXv /home/mnt/* /
```

After running this command it showed all of my files restoring to the server. However on reboot the monitor showed a selection menu and I hit "ubuntu". Some words showed on screen saying that I needed to load the kernel first. I believe this happened because the backup must have some unique identifier that overwrote the one on the fresh Ubuntu install, stopping the server from booting. I already reinstalled Ubuntu again as I think maybe I need to exclude something from the restore of the backup when I try it again. I'm pretty new to Linux so I'm hoping someone here can help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you restored /etc, then you over-wrote /etc/fstab, and this will prevent your system from booting, because it points to the partitions on the system's hard drives.

There are numerous questions on this site about how to fix fstab from a live session. Or you could just not restore it, if you reinstalled already.